# Show that f is surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

So im having a little trouble proving this. Can anyone help me out?

Let $A$, $B \subseteq E$.
Moreover, let $$f: \mathscr{P}(E) \to \mathscr{P}(A) \times \mathscr{P}(B)$$ be defined by

$$f: X \mapsto (A \cap X, B \cap X)$$

Show that $f$ is surjective iff $A \cap B = \emptyset$.

I've tried for a while to work out a proof, but I seem to be getting nowhere.

I'm new to set theory

Comment: what are A and B ? $\sigma-$algebra ? and P ? probability measure ? Am I right ?

Comment: @Imperial I think he means $A$ and $B$ are sets and $P(E) = 2^E$ the power set.

Comment: ahh sorry yes: A and B are sets in E. P(E) denotes the power set of E

Comment: @ThePhysicsStudent Let me know if you need any explanation after reading my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$. Then there exists $x\in  A\cap B$. If $f(X)=(A,\emptyset)$, $X\cap B=\emptyset$, so $x\not\in X$. But $X\cap A=A$ so $A\subseteq X$ and $x\in  X$. This is a contradiction.

For the other direction, assume that $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Let $(C,D)\in P(A)\times P(B).$ Then if $X=C\cup D$, $f(X)=(C,D).$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Prove the contrapositive.

For example, if $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$, then it is impossible to get $(A_1, \emptyset)$ for some $A_1 \subset A$ with $A_1$ non-empty.

Explicitly, take $E = \{1,2,3\}$ and $A = \{1,2\}$ and $B=\{2,3\}$. Then there is no $X \in \mathscr{P}(E)$ so that $f(X) = (\{2\}, \emptyset)$. Recall that for any set $R$, $\emptyset \in \mathscr{P}(R)$ by default.

If $A \cap B = \emptyset$, it is clear that $f$ is surjective. Surely take $(A_1,B_1) \in \mathscr{P}(A) \times \mathscr{P}(B)$, then let $ X = A_1 \cup B_1 \in \mathscr{P}(E)$, and $$f(A_1 \cup B_1) = (A_1 \cap (A_1 \cup B_1), B_1 \cap (A_1 \cup B_1))$$ and using the fact that $A \cap B = \emptyset$ as well as the rule $$A_1 \cap (A_1 \cup B_1) = (A_1 \cap A_1) \cup (A_1 \cap B_1),$$  we see that this is precisely $(A_1,B_1)$.

Comment: Anthony, why is it impotant that I cannot get (A1,null)?

Comment: @ThePhysicsStudent It's the definition of surjectivity! You have to be able to map to every element of $\mathscr{P}(A) \times \mathscr{P}(B)$, right? Well would you agree that $(A_1, \emptyset) \in \mathscr{P}(A) \times \mathscr{P}(B)$ for some $A_1$?

Comment: ahh, ok. Of course, (A,null) is in P(A) X P(B) and it doesnt get mapped to which implies f isn't a surjection. Thanks for your help Anthony!